# Angular2 dart DateTime not type save?

Tags: angular, dart

I have an Angular2 Dart application where I have the following type defined.

```
class Event {
  final int id;
  DateTime startDate;
}
```

I now want to let the user input a new date so I bind this field the following.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" required
         [(ngModel)]="event.startDate"
         ngControl="start_date"
         #start_date="ngForm">
  <div [hidden]="start_date.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
    Start date is required
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I am surprised to see that the user can input an invalid date string and that if I e.g. do a print(event.startDate) I get this invalid string. My impression was that the DateTime variable would be type safe but it just seems to behave like an ordinary string. What am I missing. I understand that I would need to add validators but why do I have a type defined in the first place? I would at least expect it to blow up :-)

So how would you go about entering dates correctly? If I change the input type to "date" then it can't even load the inital value due to the time part of the DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I now took Günters advice and solved this with the following construct:

```
class Event {
  final int id;
  DateTime startDate;

  String get startDateStr {
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    return formatter.format(startDate);
  }

  void set startDateStr(String date) {
    startDate = DateTime.parse(date);
  }
}
```

With this extra properties it is now possible to write the following in the html template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" required
         [(ngModel)]="event.startDateStr"
         ngControl="start_date"
         #start_date="ngForm">
  <div [hidden]="start_date.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
    Start date is required
  </div>
</div>
```

This looks to me the cleanest and preserves the Event class structure. I still would be interested if there is a common pattern for something like this, if yes please comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In production mode there are not type information. They are only available in checked (development mode).

It's not clear what mode you're using.

The Input elements value is a string and you need to take care yourself to get it in `DateTime` format (`DateTime.parse()`). 
Just because a variable you use is of type `DateTime` doesn't mean anything you "throw" at it automatically becomes a valid date.

Comment: Well I am using pub serve and Dartium so I thought that would be a development setup.

Comment: I just mentioned that so you are aware that there is a difference. The other parts of my answer apply no matter what mode you use. You probably get different errors depending on the mode.

Comment: Thanks and I now know and I fully understand that. I was just wondering why my error went silent, but that is explained by the production mode. Still I have no idea how to bind a DateTime. I e.g. tried: [ngModel]="event.startDate | date: 'y-M-d'" to set the initial value but that ends up in a display of 'tt.mm.jjjj'

Comment: `ngModel` uses the `value´ property. Check https://dartpad.dartlang.org/191ca4b46d0ea30cafa67e536e46f141. Select a date and click the button, then check the console output (link on the top right). What you can do is bind to a getter/setter that converts between `String` and `DateTime` or build a custom `MyDateTimeComponent` component  with a `ControlValueAccessor` that wraps `<input type="datetime">` for easier reuse  (this still requires you to implement the conversion between `String` and `DateTime`.